# Does es2015 in stage-2 still legit to stage-3?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

As I have known so far, when we work with env = production, we should choose stage-3 or 4 for its stability. What if I write some thing in the latest js syntax then transpile with stage-2 preset into es2015, is it still legit to stage-3 and more, I mean will it still has the stability of stage-3 for the production env? I think es2015 is already legit to stage-3. Sorry if the question confuses you and thanks in advance.
For example:

```
class B {
  b = 'b';
  _b = () => "This is B";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage 2 is Draft

and stage 3 is candidate.

So a stage 3 proposal is **likely** to stay the same, but is not guaranteed to make it to the actual language release (if some critical issue is discovered, for instance).

But stage 2 proposals are not *supposed* to stay the same, they are *drafts*. The very goal of this stage is to fine tune things, and modify them to better achieve whatever the goal is.

More info on ECMAScript evolution process here :

http://2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html

Here is the some details from the above link :

> **Stage 2: draft**
>   **What is it?** A first version of what will be in the
>   specification. At this point, an eventual inclusion of the feature in
>   the standard is likely.
>
> **What’s required?** The proposal must now additionally have a formal
>   description of the syntax and semantics of the feature (using the
>   formal language of the ECMAScript specification). The description
>   should be as complete as possible, but can contain todos and
>   placeholders. Two experimental implementations of the feature are
>   needed, but one of them can be in a transpiler such as Babel.
>
> **What’s next?** Only incremental changes are expected from now on.
>
> **Stage 3:** candidate
>   **What is it?** The proposal is mostly finished and
>   now needs feedback from implementations and users to progress further.
>
> **What’s required?** The spec text must be complete. Designated reviewers
>   (appointed by TC39, not by the champion) and the ECMAScript spec
>   editor must sign off on the spec text. There must be at least two
>   spec-compliant implementations (which don’t have to be enabled by
>   default).
>
> **What’s next?** Henceforth, changes should only be made in response to
>   critical issues raised by the implementations and their use.
>
> **Stage 4:** finished
>   **What is it?** The proposal is ready to be included
>   in the standard.
>
> **What’s required?** The following things are needed before a proposal can
>   reach this stage:
>
> Test 262 acceptance tests (roughly, unit tests for the language
>   feature, written in JavaScript). Two spec-compliant shipping
>   implementations that pass the tests. Significant practical experience
>   with the implementations. The ECMAScript spec editor must sign off on
>   the spec text. What’s next? The proposal will be included in the
>   ECMAScript specification as soon as possible. When the spec goes
>   through its yearly ratification as a standard, the proposal is
>   ratified as part of it.